# How to exclude mobile devices from the following CSS rule

Tags: css

I have the following CSS property affecting the display of content on web pages on my website. However, I want to exclude the rule from applying on mobile devices.

Kindly help me modify it.

***I'm applying it on WordPress under customization, additional CSS***

```
.entry-content, .entry-summary {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
        width: 66.67%;
}
```

Comment: `media queries`

Comment: @pavel Maybe it's not about the size, maybe it's about touch devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found a perfect answer to exclude the elements from being enforced on mobile devices. You can adjust the pixels entry on `min-width` or swap it with `max-width` if you wish.

***Either rule applies***

```
@media (min-width: 900px) { 
    .entry-content, .entry-summary {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 66.67%;
    }
}
```

and

```
@media (min-width: 900px) { 
    .entry-content, .entry-summary {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 66.67%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have your markup I will improvise:

```js
// Get all elements with classes which you want to exclude if device has touch screen
let touch_divs1 = document.getElementsByClassName('entry-content');
let touch_divs2 = document.getElementsByClassName('entry-summary');
let is_touch_device = false;
// Check if device is a touch device
if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {
    is_touch_device = true;
}
// Go through all elements which have those classes and remove them
if (is_touch_device) {
    for (let i = 0; i < touch_divs1.length; i++) {
        touch_divs1[i].classList.remove('entry-content');
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < touch_divs2.length; i++) {
        touch_divs2[i].classList.remove('entry-summary');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I wish to apply it on WordPress custom CSS feature.

Comment: You could, but you are probably not familiar with JavaScript

Comment: True. I'm a newbie in this stuff